# Diferrence between registers

Tags: sql, database, postgresql-8.4

I want to take what internation return to my hospital in less than 72hs , for example:

```
id_People    id_issue    internation_in       internation_out
444          456789      2014-01-01      2014-01-07
444          465465      2014-02-10      2014-02-12
444          789564      2014-02-13      2014-02-20
```

- Difference between internation_out 456789 - internation_in 465465=LESS than 72hs NO
- Difference between internation_out 465465-internation_in 789564= LESS than 72hs YES

Amount of reingress less than 72 hs = 1

Comment: Could you explain what your question is and what you would like to achieve, please?

Comment: the people who came in in an interval less than 72 hours

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to measure the times between someone leaving and then returning:

```
select t.*,
       (case when internation_out + interval '72 hour' >
                  lag(internation_out) over (partition by id_people order by internaion_in)
             then 'YES'
             else 'NO'
        end)
from table t;
```

Comment: What about them?  You don't mention them in the question at all, although they are included as a column in the sample data.